# how to use grep to match with either whitespace or newline

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I want to grep a file with a word, say "AAA", and it ends with whitespace or newlines. I know how to write this seperately, as follows, but having problems in combining them (in the sense that it outputs both `VVV AAA` and `AAA VVV`).

```
$echo -e "AAA VVV \nVVV AAA\nBBB" | grep "AAA$" 
>VVV AAA
$echo -e "AAA VVV \nVVV AAA\nBBB" | grep "AAA[[:space:]]" 
>AAA VVV
```

I have tried using `[]`, but without success..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are looking for word `AAA` followed by space anywhere in the string, or at the end of line, then use

```
grep -P "AAA( |$)"
```

Comment: -P, --perl-regexp
              Interpret   PATTERNS   as  Perl-compatible  regular  expressions
              (PCREs).  This option is experimental when combined with the  -z
              (--null-data)  option,  and  grep  -P  may warn of unimplemented
              features.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `-e` option of grep to select many patterns:

```
grep -e "AAA$" -e "AAA[[:space:]]"
```

From the grep man:

```
-e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
      Use  PATTERN  as  the  pattern.   This  can  be  used to specify
      multiple search patterns, or to protect a pattern beginning with
      a hyphen (-).  (-e is specified by POSIX.)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `"AAA\b"` if it's acceptable to also match AAA followed by any other non-alphanumeric character. According to the [grep man pages](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep), `\b` matches the empty string at the edge of a word.

```
$ echo -e "AAA VVV \nVVV AAA\nBBB" | grep "AAA\b"
AAA VVV
VVV AAA
```

Comment: Using `\b` would match also inputs such as `AAA-BBB`

Answer (score 0):

I think we can also use default grep with OR(\|)

```
echo -e "AAA VVV \nVVV AAA\nBBB" | grep "AAA$\|AAA "
```

Comment: On most systems you'll need `egrep` to support the OR regex operator: `egrep $'(AAA|VVV)($|[[:space:]])'`