# How to grep to make the list of all PHP classes from all the files?

Tags: php, regex, command-line, grep

I'm trying to grep all the files containing the class names, in example:

```
$ grep -ER "(^| )class [^ ]*" .
```

Where I thought `(^| )` would include [either whitespace or newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220192/how-to-use-grep-to-match-with-either-whitespace-or-newline), but it's showing all class words within the comments such as:

```
./includes/bootstrap.inc: *   The name of the class to check or load.
```

And the following example:

```
grep -ER "(^|\?abstract)class [^ ]*" .
```

actually doesn't include any abstract class files.

Basically I'm trying to do the regex such as:

1. New line or space.
2. Optional word `abstract`.
3. `class` name (word).
4. Space after it.
5. Any actual class name (word).

So the regex would react on the following lines:

```
  class Entity {
class Entity {
class NoFieldsException extends Exception {}
abstract class CacheArray implements ArrayAccess {
```

But not for these:

```
 * This class should be extended by systems that need to cache large amounts
```

---

Setting up the testing environment:

```
$ curl -o- http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-7.31.tar.gz | tar zxf - && cd drupal-7*
$ grep -ER "(^| )class [^ ]*" . | less
$ grep -ER "(^|\?abstract)class [^ ]*" . | wc -l
653 # But this doesn't include ./includes/bootstrap.inc:abstract class DrupalCacheArray
```

---

Example use cases:

- In case when Drupal CMS class registry is broken, [the table needs to be rebuilt](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133590/how-to-rebuild-registry-table), so all available files containing classes needs to be imported into SQL table.

Comment: You should use a prior regex to clean out comments, non-php sections, and strings. Then extracting class names is quite simple.

Comment: This will never work reliably. Too many possible points of failure. What about another strategy: find all files, include then one after another, if successful compare the list of defined classes before and after the loading of a file. Should be much more precise, though slower.

Comment: It's difficult to say if specific line is the comment it-self, because could contain `*`, or could not. So excluding multiple words before `class` word or limiting only to one special word (e.g. `abstract`) I think should do the better job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As arkascha mentions, there are probably too many possibilities to have this done with regex, however given the examples you have, this should work for them:

```
/^(\s+)?(abstract\s+)?class\s+(\S+)/igm
```

See it in action: http://regex101.com/r/qM7iO0/4

Comment: Thanks, it seem to work, `grep -ER "^(\s+)?(abstract )?class (\S+)" .` which is finding by coincidence 666 classes:)

Comment: @kenorb I updated it as well to match if there are multiple spaces and/or newlines between the words. Try running it again.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to my other answer is to allow PHP to handle it without actually executing the code by using the [tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php). This way you should not have any of the negative side-effects of an incorrect regex since PHP is doing all the parsing.

### test1.php:

```
<?php

$source = file_get_contents('test2.php');
$tokens = token_get_all($source);

foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    // 308 is for classes
    if ($token[0] == 308) {
        // $token[1] contains the actual class name
        echo $token[1] ."\n";
    }
}
```

### test2.php:

```
  class Entity { }
class                                             Entity {
}
class NoFieldsException extends Exception {}
abstract
    class
             CacheArray implements ArrayAccess { }
// But not for these:

 /* This class should be extended by systems that need to cache large amounts */
```

### Output:

```
Entity
Entity
NoFieldsException
Exception
CacheArray
ArrayAccess
```

Note, it may not be desirable to have `Exception` and `ArrayAccess` show up in here too since one is a native PHP class and the other is being implemented. If not, try doing a `print_r($tokens);` and playing around with it to get what you want. You could also add them all to an array and then do `array_unique()` to get the unique values.