# How do I match a string ending in whitespace using grep in Perl?

Tags: perl, grep

I want to call grep in a Perl script like so:

```
my $line = `grep "^$name\b" $inputFile`;
```

When I run the actual grep command in the terminal, it returns what is expected, but when I include this line in my script, nothing is returned.

If I replace the `\b` with a `\s`, it complains with "Unrecognized escape \s passed through at test.pl line 50."

I've already looked at [how to use grep to match with either whitespace or newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220192/how-to-use-grep-to-match-with-either-whitespace-or-newline), but it doesn't have specifics to why my script isn't returning the expected.

How do I properly include the `\b` or `\s` in the command in Perl?

Comment: FYI, `\b` matches at the boundary of a word character (in the C locale with ASCII encoding, that would be a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and underscore) and a non-word character. That means it doesn't match when you have a dash followed by a space, for example. Something to keep in mind in case any of your `$name` values can end in punctuation characters.

Comment: To see the command you are about to execute, use `print qq\`grep "^$name\b" $inputFile\`, "\n";`. You'll see the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to escape the '\' use grep \\b

Comment: @ZebraSocks `\s` isn't supported by grep's basic or extended regular expression syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use backticks -- you write it in Perl

```
my $name = 'xyz';

my $line;

while ( <> ) {
    next unless /^$name\b/;
    $line = $_;
    last;
}
```

This would be likely to be much less clumsy if the context of the test were known. You may need to escape the contents of `$name` if you wish to pass regex metacharacters through